# if $f_{n}(x)=f(f_{n-1}(x))$then $f_{10}(x)=x,x\in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

> Define the function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ by the following.
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> x+\dfrac{1}{2},&0\le x\le\dfrac{1}{2}\\
> 2(1-x),&\dfrac{1}{2}<x\le 1.
> \end{cases}$$ Let $f_1(x)=f(x)$ and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}\cap[2,\infty)$, define $f_n(x)$ as
>   $$f_{n}(x)=f(f_{n-1}(x)).$$  Finally, define the sets $A$ and $B$ by $$A=\{x\in[0,1]\,|\,f_{10}(x)=x\}, B=\left\{\dfrac{2}{15},\dfrac{2}{3},0,\dfrac{1}{2},1\right\}.$$

1. Determine the intersection of $A$ and $B$.
2. Determine the cardinality of $A$.

my idea: since $$0\le x\le\dfrac{1}{2},\Longrightarrow x+\dfrac{1}{2}\in [\dfrac{1}{2},1]$$
and
$$\dfrac{1}{2}<x\le 1\Longrightarrow 2(1-x)\in [0,\dfrac{1}{2}]$$
so
$$f_{2}(x)=f(f_{1}(x))=\begin{cases}
2(1-(x+\dfrac{1}{2}))=1-2x&0\le x\le \dfrac{1}{2}\\
2(1-x)+\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{5}{2}-2x&\dfrac{1}{2}<x\le 1
\end{cases}$$
follow. I think this problem will take some time to solve. Maybe there are other methods? Thank you

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{2}<x\le 1\Longrightarrow 2(1-x)\in [0,\dfrac{1}{2}]$ is wrong. And the first question is easy, just calculate $f_{10}$ for all elements of $B$.

Answer (score 5):

## 1. Overview

$$
\large\mathit{\mbox{``A picture is worth a 1000 words''}}^{\tiny\,\,\,\mbox{but is no rigorous proof}}
$$

```
fp(x) = (x <= 0.5) ? (x + 0.5) : 2*(1 - x)
fp10(x) = fp(fp(fp(fp(fp(fp(fp(fp(fp(fp(x))))))))))
plot [0:1][0:1] fp10(x), x, 2.0/15, 2.0/3, 0, 1.0/2, 1
```

[image: fp10(x) - the 10-fold iterated f]

Fun aside, this gives a first orientation. Let us go through the candidates from $B$:

- $P_1 = 2/15$ (blue line) is hard to judge in this view, might be a sampling error or not a fixed point.
- $P_2 = 2/3$ (magenta line) nicely crosses $\mbox{id}(x) = x$, that one is in $A$
- $P_3 = 0$  (cyan line), can't see, have to think later (but should be easy)
- $P_4 = 1/2$ (brown line), looks like a hit
- $P_5 = 1$ (black line), can't see in this resolution

Now let the machine do again the hard work:

```
gnuplot> print p1, fp10(p1)
0.133333333333333 0.133333333333326
gnuplot> print p2, fp10(p2)
0.666666666666667 0.666666666666629
gnuplot> print p3, fp10(p3)
0 0.5
gnuplot> print p4, fp10(p4)
0.5 1.0
gnuplot> print p5, fp10(p5)
1 0.0
```

The development of $P_1$ is

```
gnuplot> print p1, f(p1), f2(p1), f3(p1), f4(p1), f5(p1)
0.133333333333333 0.633333333333333 0.733333333333333 0.533333333333333
0.933333333333334 0.133333333333333
```

## 2. Checking $A \cap B$

$$
\begin{align}
f(P_1) & = f(2/15) = 2/15 + 1/2 = 19/30 > 1/2 \\
f(19/30) & = 2(1 - 19/30) = 11 / 15 > 1/2 \\
f(11/15) & = 2(1 - 11/15) = 8 / 15 > 1/2 \\
f(8/15) & = 2(1 - 8/15) = 14 / 15 > 1/2 \\
f(14/15) & = 2(1 - 14/15) = 2/15  = P_1
\end{align}
$$

Thus $f_5(P_1) = P_1$ and therefore $f_{10}(P_1) = P_1$.

Then we have for $P_2$:
$$
f(P_2) = f(2/3) = 2(1 - 2/3) = 2/3 = P_2
$$
and thus $f_{10}(P_2) = P_2$.

Now let us look at one iteration to see what is going on for $P_3, P_4, P_5$:

[image: A closer look at f]

$$
f(P_3) = P_4, \quad f(P_4) = P_5, \quad  f(P_5) = P_3
$$

Taking 10 iterations one gets
$$
f_{10}(P_3) = P_4 \ne P_3, \quad f_{10}(P_4) = P_5 \ne P_4, \quad  f_{10}(P_5) = P_3 \ne P_5.
$$

It looks like $A \cap B = \{ P_1 = 2/15, P_2 = 2/3 \}$.

## 3. Counting $A$

Now about $|A|$ which I interpret as the number of fixed points of $f_{10}$ on $[0, 1]$.

For this we have to look at the fixed points of $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_5$ and $f_{10}$ to understand what is going on.

[image: f1, f2, f5]
[image: f1, f2, f5, f10]

As one can see the graphical methods, counting crossings hits its limits for higher iterations. For $f_{10}$ one would need to look at small resolutions.

Estimation: With every evaluation of $f$ there is one comparison involved, so for $f_{10}$ we talk about up to $2^{10} = 1024$ cases here.

Let $s(k)$ be the number of straight line segments of $f_k$ then I counted

$$
s = (2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, \ldots)
$$

on the graphs. This is obviously a Fibonacci series. So there should be $s(10) = 144$ straight line segments, which gives a first upper bound for the number of fixed points $|A|$. This is an observation, I can give no proof for $s(k)$ yet.

### 3.1 The Secant Method

Next I wrote a numeric fixed point solver and that spew out $|A| = 123$, using $1024$ subintervals. See [program](https://gist.github.com/mvw/cff0beef0cd8fee6a459) and [output](https://gist.github.com/mvw/e2e857c881dfdf95491a).

As $f_{10}$ is piecewise linear,

$$
x_0 = x, \\
x_k = a_k\, x_{k - 1} + b_k  \quad (k > 0) \\
(a_k, b_k) \in \{ (1, 1/2), \, (-2, 2) \}
$$

with rational coefficients $a_k$ and $b_k$

$$
f_{10}(x) =  \alpha_{10} x + \beta_{10} \\
\alpha_{10} = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{10}a_k \\
\beta_1 = b_1 \\
\beta_{k} = a_k \, \beta_{k-1} + b_k \quad (k > 1) \\
f_{10}(x^*) = x^* \iff x^* = \frac{\beta_{10}}{1 - \alpha_{10}} \in \mathbb{Q} \quad(*)
$$

the fixed points are rational numbers.

Thus I updated the numerical program to search and display the fractions.
This yields:

$$
A = \left\{ \frac{2}{129}, \frac{1}{63}, \frac{5}{129}, \frac{2}{51}, \frac{8}{129}, \frac{4}{63}, \frac{14}{129}, \frac{1}{9}, \frac{17}{129}, \frac{2}{15}, \frac{20}{129}, \frac{8}{51}, \frac{86}{513}, \frac{43}{255}, \frac{23}{129}, \frac{46}{255}, \frac{26}{129}, \frac{13}{63}, \frac{29}{129}, \frac{58}{255}, \frac{32}{129}, \frac{16}{63}, \frac{38}{129}, \frac{19}{63}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{22}{63}, \frac{50}{129}, \frac{25}{63}, \frac{53}{129}, \frac{106}{255}, \frac{56}{129}, \frac{4}{9}, \frac{62}{129}, \frac{31}{63}, \frac{65}{129}, \frac{26}{51}, \frac{133}{258}, \frac{65}{126}, \frac{68}{129}, \frac{8}{15}, \frac{139}{258}, \frac{55}{102}, \frac{278}{513}, \frac{139}{255}, \frac{71}{129}, \frac{142}{255}, \frac{145}{258}, \frac{71}{126}, \frac{74}{129}, \frac{37}{63}, \frac{77}{129}, \frac{154}{255}, \frac{157}{258}, \frac{11}{18}, \frac{80}{129}, \frac{32}{51}, \frac{163}{258}, \frac{19}{30}, \frac{326}{513}, \frac{163}{255}, \frac{83}{129}, \frac{166}{255}, \frac{169}{258}, \frac{67}{102}, \frac{338}{513}, \frac{169}{255}, \frac{341}{513}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{685}{1026}, \frac{341}{510}, \frac{344}{513}, \frac{172}{255}, \frac{175}{258}, \frac{347}{510}, \frac{350}{513}, \frac{35}{51}, \frac{89}{129}, \frac{178}{255}, \frac{181}{258}, \frac{89}{126}, \frac{92}{129}, \frac{184}{255}, \frac{187}{258}, \frac{371}{510}, \frac{374}{513}, \frac{11}{15}, \frac{95}{129}, \frac{38}{51}, \frac{193}{258}, \frac{95}{126}, \frac{98}{129}, \frac{7}{9}, \frac{101}{129}, \frac{202}{255}, \frac{205}{258}, \frac{101}{126}, \frac{104}{129}, \frac{52}{63}, \frac{5}{6}, \frac{107}{126}, \frac{110}{129}, \frac{55}{63}, \frac{113}{129}, \frac{226}{255}, \frac{229}{258}, \frac{113}{126}, \frac{116}{129}, \frac{232}{255}, \frac{235}{258}, \frac{467}{510}, \frac{470}{513}, \frac{47}{51}, \frac{119}{129}, \frac{14}{15}, \frac{241}{258}, \frac{17}{18}, \frac{122}{129}, \frac{61}{63}, \frac{125}{129}, \frac{50}{51}, \frac{253}{258}, \frac{125}{126}, \frac{128}{129} \right\}, \, |A| = 123
$$

### 3.2 Looking for Cycles

Another update of the program yielded the partition of $A$ into

$$
A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_5 \cup A_{10}
$$

with

$$
A_{1} = \left\{ \frac{2}{3} \right\}, |A_{1}| = 1 \\
A_{2} = \left\{ \frac{1}{3}, \frac{5}{6} \right\}, |A_{2}| = 2 \\
A_{5} = \left\{ \frac{1}{9}, \frac{2}{15}, \frac{4}{9}, \frac{8}{15}, \frac{11}{18}, \frac{19}{30}, \frac{11}{15}, \frac{7}{9}, \frac{14}{15}, \frac{17}{18} \right\}, |A_{5}| = 10 = 2 \cdot 5\\
A_{10} = \left\{ \frac{2}{129}, \frac{1}{63}, \frac{5}{129}, \frac{2}{51}, \frac{8}{129}, \frac{4}{63}, \frac{14}{129}, \frac{17}{129}, \frac{20}{129}, \frac{8}{51}, \frac{86}{513}, \frac{43}{255}, \frac{23}{129}, \frac{46}{255}, \frac{26}{129}, \frac{13}{63}, \frac{29}{129}, \frac{58}{255}, \frac{32}{129}, \frac{16}{63}, \frac{38}{129}, \frac{19}{63}, \frac{22}{63}, \frac{50}{129}, \frac{25}{63}, \frac{53}{129}, \frac{106}{255}, \frac{56}{129}, \frac{62}{129}, \frac{31}{63}, \frac{65}{129}, \frac{26}{51}, \frac{133}{258}, \frac{65}{126}, \frac{68}{129}, \frac{139}{258}, \frac{55}{102}, \frac{278}{513}, \frac{139}{255}, \frac{71}{129}, \frac{142}{255}, \frac{145}{258}, \frac{71}{126}, \frac{74}{129}, \frac{37}{63}, \frac{77}{129}, \frac{154}{255}, \frac{157}{258}, \frac{80}{129}, \frac{32}{51}, \frac{163}{258}, \frac{326}{513}, \frac{163}{255}, \frac{83}{129}, \frac{166}{255}, \frac{169}{258}, \frac{67}{102}, \frac{338}{513}, \frac{169}{255}, \frac{341}{513}, \frac{685}{1026}, \frac{341}{510}, \frac{344}{513}, \frac{172}{255}, \frac{175}{258}, \frac{347}{510}, \frac{350}{513}, \frac{35}{51}, \frac{89}{129}, \frac{178}{255}, \frac{181}{258}, \frac{89}{126}, \frac{92}{129}, \frac{184}{255}, \frac{187}{258}, \frac{371}{510}, \frac{374}{513}, \frac{95}{129}, \frac{38}{51}, \frac{193}{258}, \frac{95}{126}, \frac{98}{129}, \frac{101}{129}, \frac{202}{255}, \frac{205}{258}, \frac{101}{126}, \frac{104}{129}, \frac{52}{63}, \frac{107}{126}, \frac{110}{129}, \frac{55}{63}, \frac{113}{129}, \frac{226}{255}, \frac{229}{258}, \frac{113}{126}, \frac{116}{129}, \frac{232}{255}, \frac{235}{258}, \frac{467}{510}, \frac{470}{513}, \frac{47}{51}, \frac{119}{129}, \frac{241}{258}, \frac{122}{129}, \frac{61}{63}, \frac{125}{129}, \frac{50}{51}, \frac{253}{258}, \frac{125}{126}, \frac{128}{129} \right\}, |A_{10}| = 110 = 11 \cdot 10
$$

where $A_k$ is the set of fixed points of order $k = \min\{ i \left|\,\, f_i(x^*) = x^* \right. \}$.

Comment: Hello,My I have only this problem answer,$|A|=123$

Comment: I got the same numerically. Can you give some background info about this problem? Maybe that helps to guess the domain of the solution technique. Maybe it is very simple, maybe advanced algebra. I take a break now. :-)

Comment: I just came up with an idea that might be developable into an elegant solution: Divide $[0,1]$ into $12$ equal intervals, you end up with $13$ points labeled from $0$ to $12$. I will call those points fields, because this turns out to be like some of those board games where on uses dice to move. Let the iteration $f$ act on the fields, note on what field you will get moved by it. I end up with $3$ basic graphs which allow me to forecast fixed points for various $f_k$. There should be more suitable board system than the $1/12$ system. I hope one will allow even to analyse $f_{10}$.

Answer (score 2):

In a nice computation-based analysis, mvw observed a Fibonacci-like structure in the graphs of the functions $f_n$.  This structure is easy to prove by thinking inductively about the composition of the function.  Each graph consists of a sequence of "short" and "long" segments, where each short segment has $[1/2,1]$ for its range and each long segment has the entire interval $[0,1]$ for its range.  Given the graph for $f$, each short segment becomes a long segment in the next iteration, while each long segment splits into a long segment plus a short segment (the split occurs at the midpoint).  Symbolically, we have $s\to L$ and $L\to Ls$ at each iteration.  This clearly leads to Fibonacci numbers:  $s\to L\to Ls\to L^2s\to L^3s^2\to L^5s^3\to\ldots$.

Consequently, by $f_{10}$, the short segment for $f=f_1$ has split into $21$ short segments and $34$ long ones, while the long segment has split into $55$ long segments and $34$ short ones, for a total of $144$ segments, as mvw observed.  The reason for keeping separate counts is for the purpose of determining the cardinality of the OP's set $A$, the solutions to $f_{10}(x)=x$:  Each long segment intersects the straight line $y=x$ exactly once, but of the short segments, only the ones with *domain* in $[1/2,1]$ do so.  Thus

$$|A|=34+55+34=123$$

which also agrees with what mvw found computationally.

As for the intersection of $A$ and $B=\{{2\over15},{2\over3},0,{1\over2},1\}$, I agree with the comment by N.S., that this is perhaps best found by straightforward computation of $f_{10}(x)$ for those five values.

One comment regarding mvw's graphs:  The sawteeth there are much more ragged and irregular than they are in actuality -- in actuality, the max's and min's are all at $0$, $1/2$ and $1$.  This flaw in the graphs is presumably because of default settings in the plotting algorithm (the fault is in default...).  As mvw astutely said upfront, a picture is worth a thousand words, but is no rigorous proof.

Comment: Hi Barry thanks for providing a short, elegant proof! I am not sure if I would have come up with it in the next days. This problem first looked alien then started to get more and more interesting the more I looked at it and was a nice reason to do some numerically programming. The problem with the plots is the proper sampling rate, how fine and where to locate the points. I was hoping for increasing insight when playing with it.

Comment: @mvw, thanks, your computational insights were a big help.  It seems clear (in retrospect at least) that the proper sample points for the plots are fractions with powers of $2$ in the denominator.